# How can I use SQL to count copied rows based on a "previous_id" column?

Tags: sql, subquery

I am working with a table like this:

| ticket | previous_ticket |
| --- | --- |
| A600100001 | A600100001 |
| A600100002 | A600100001 |
| A600100003 | A600100002 |
| A600100004 | A600100004 |

The ticket number in "ticket" is system-generated when a ticket is created. A duplicate value is placed in "previous_ticket" at the same time. However, if a ticket is copied, the "ticket" field will get a new ticket number and the previous ticket number will be listed in the "previous_ticket" field. The first three rows above provide an example of this process. There is an original ticket, a copy, then another copy. There is no limit to how many times a copy can occur. Unfortunately, the original ticket number is not retained in any field.

I need to count the instances of tickets being copied over time. Is there some way to use the "previous_ticket" field to do this, perhaps using nested queries?

Thanks

Comment: Could A600100005 be a copy of any ticket that came before it or can it only be a copy of A600100004?

Comment: I think what you want is a recursive CTE  https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

Comment: A600100005 can be a copy of any ticket that came before it @RossBush